# Git repository broken after computer crash

Tags: git

I turned my computer off after putting in to sleep and discovered it was a hard reset, not sleep. My git repo got broken. Fortunately, I've committed and pushed everything so I just need to reset it to a pristine state. Here is what I get when I run `git fsck --full`

```
$ git fsck --full
error: Invalid HEAD
error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method)
error: unable to unpack 0485493a56ad42802b72cee71522666628294e3d header
error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method)
fatal: loose object 0485493a56ad42802b72cee71522666628294e3d (stored in .git/objects/04/85493a56ad42802b72cee71522666628294e3d) is corrupt
```

I was on `betterfmgr` branch but the `.git/refs/heads/betterfmgr` is an empty file. Any idea how to fix it? I could just clone it again but I need to copy zillion of `node_modules` and copy over my `.idea` files.

Comment: Does `git reflog betterfmgr` give you anything? Do you remember by any chance some unique string in your last commit on this branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following : get a fresh and sane copy of the `.git/` directory from a new clone of the remote repository

---

I will try to illustrate the idea :

```
git clone sources_server:repo newdir/   # make a git clone, in a new directory

cd newdir/
git checkout betterfmgr  # set active branch to 'betterfmgr'
cd ..

cd olddir/   # go into your original working copy,
             # with current node_modules/ dir, .idea files, etc ...

mv .git/ .git.old/

mv ../newdir/.git .git   # get ".git/" folder from other repository

# now check if everything looks like you expected :
git status ...
git diff ...
git difftool -d ...
idea ...

# if all looks well, remove old dir :
rm -rf .git.old
```

Note that this will loose your local branches and your reflog, though.

Answer (score 2):

If you pushed everything as you said it, just make a git clone in another directory and delete the broken repo.